# Problemas para implementar Spring Security

Tags: jsf, spring, spring-security

Estou implementando **Spring Security** em um projeto, porém, tenho me deparado com alguns problemas. Vou por o código dos contextos, a parte do `web.xml` pra **Spring Security** e como pus em uma página pra vocês verem.

O que acontece é que o Spring não está fazendo restrições. Tenho apenas um usuário no banco com permissão ROLE_GERENTE, porém, o Spring leva da página de login para a home restrita sem apresentar os conteúdos de gerente que deveria (vide tag no código abaixo). Além disso, mantém a URL da página de login ("publico/home.jsf").

**applicationContext-security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">
    <http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/restrito/**" access="ROLE_GERENTE"/>
        <form-login 
            login-page="/publico/home.jsf"
            always-use-default-target="true" 
            default-target-url="/publico/home.jsf"
            authentication-failure-url="/publico/index.jsf?login_error=1" />
        <logout/>
        <remember-me/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
<!--            <password-encoder hash="md5"/> -->
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="Somore"
                authorities-by-username-query="SELECT u.email, p.permissao FROM usuario u, 
                                usuario_permissao p WHERE u.id = p.usuario AND u.email= ?"
                users-by-username-query="SELECT email, senha, ativo FROM usuario WHERE email = ?" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</b:beans>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" id="Somore">
        <property name="jndiName" >
            <value>java:comp/env/jdbc/Somore</value>
        </property>
    </bean>     
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<!-- Spring Security -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

**restrito/home.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>  
<ui:composition 
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/facelets/tags" 
    template="/resources/templates/template_restrito.xhtml">        

    <ui:define name="section">      
        <sec:ifAnyGranted roles="ROLE_GERENTE">
            GERENTE<br />
        </sec:ifAnyGranted>

    </ui:define>    

</ui:composition>
```

**Diálogo de login**

```
<p:dialog resizable="false" reshowEffect="Puff" widgetVar="dlgLogar" 
    modal="true" showHeader="false" closeOnEscape="true" height="175" width="430">
    <h:form id="login" method="post" action="${request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check">
    <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="panelLogar">
        <p:outputLabel value="Login"/>
        <p:inputText styleClass="input" value="#{usuarioBean.usuarioSpring}" name="j_username"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="Senha"/>
        <p:password styleClass="input" maxlength="8" value="#{usuarioBean.senha}" name="j_password"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="Lembre de mim"/>
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox name="_spring_security_remember_me"/>

        <p:commandButton ajax="false" value="Logar" action="#{usuarioBean.logar}" style="width:105%;"/>
        <p:commandButton ajax="false" value="Esqueci a senha" style="width:100%;" />
    </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

**Jars**

[image: Lista de JARs]

Answer (score 1):

Gente, acabei conseguindo resolver aqui. O problema foi que meu botão de login não era do tipo submit. Agora está funcionando, precisando que eu arrume agora só a questão das permissões.